# Python - Projecting different shapefiles in the same folder

Tags: python, arcpy, coordinate-system

I have a few shapefiles in one folder with different coordinate systems but would like to use one of them as a template dataset. Is there a way to use python to filter out the shapefiles already in the required projection in the same folder?

I have been looking at the ListFeatureClasses and somehow using a wildcard, but not sure if that's the right way to go.

Comment: This is a near duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141351/how-to-change-different-projections-of-feature-classes-in-geodatabase-to-one-pro - the only difference seems to be the use of a file geodatabase instead of a folder of shapefiles.

Comment: Oh sorry, thanks for pointing out PolyGeo, I will try.

Comment: Is there a way to filter out the shapefiles already in the required projection in the same folder?

Comment: You should probably research/ask that as a new question but the way I would try is to use arcpy.Describe().

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Describe](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/heLP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//03q30000008q000000) function to get information about your spatial references.  Then simply use logic to screen out the spatial reference you do not want.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\path\to\your\fgdb.gdb'

fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in fcs:
    sr = arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference.name
    # Note that you can add multiple spatial references in a list ["sr1", "sr2"...]
    if sr not in ["NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_15N"]:
        # Do something
        print sr
```